# TFS 2008 Gated Checked-in builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2008

I have a build in TFS 2008 that gets triggered for every check-in, and what I need is following

- If the source code checkedin by the developers has any errors, then the code changes should not be checked in
- If any of the tests fails in the test    project, then the code changes should    not be checked in
- If the build script    fails for ny reason then then the    code changes should not be checked in

I have the following queries

1. Does the [Buddybuild](http://buddybuild.codeplex.com/) solves this problem?
2. I run some unit tests as part of my build script (standard way), however when the unit tests fails, the buddy build still checkin the code ? How can i make sure that the checkins are not applied when the test fails or if the build fails for any reason? Is there a variable that I can set to make sure that the buddy build does not checkin the code? After looking at the buddy build targets file, it seems like setting $(CheckInOnBuddyBuildSuccess) to false would do it ? Is this the correct approach?

Awaiting

Nabeel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://buddybuild.codeplex.com/discussions/251517